# Traduction de "kick myself"

Tags: traduction, pronoms-réfléchis

> I want to kick myself for forgetting the appointment yesterday.

Quelle est la bonne traduction ?

> (a) Je veux **me** botter pour avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.
>
> (b) Je veux botter **moi-même** pour avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.
>
> (c) Je veux **me** botter **moi-même** pour avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to an expression faithful to the original English phrasing "kick oneself", you can say, for instance:

> Je me donnerais des **baffes** pour/d' avoir oublié ...
>
> Je me **giflerais** pour/d' avoir oublié ...

... though in French, it is more like "punching oneself".

That said, one of the most common phrases to express this "cross with myself" idea is:

> Je **m'en veux d**'avoir oublié ...

Answer (score 3):

- (a) personne ne dirait ça. Quand il signifie *to kick*<sup>1</sup>, botter a besoin d'un complément d'objet (botter le derrière, botter en touche...). Une traduction littérale pourrait être:

  > je veux me botter les fesses pour avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.

  Ce serait compris mais ce n'est pas du tout idiomatique.
- (b) est incorrect. Ça signifie que l'on veut donner un coup de pied soi-même mais sans préciser dans quoi.
- (c) à le même problème que (a). De plus, *moi-même* insiste sur le *je*, ce n'est pas la cible du coup de pied.

Je ne vois pas d'expression idiomatique où quelqu'un exprime le souhait de se frapper lui-même. Je suggérerais plutôt :

> Je m'en veux à mort d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.

Cette expression est courante et bien plus bénigne qu'elle ne paraît. Si « mort » semble trop fort, on peut aussi dire:

> Je m'en veux sérieusement d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.
>
> Je m'en veux grave d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.

« Grave » est du français relâché et controversé ici.

<sup>1</sup><sub>C'est un peu tiré par les cheveux mais « je veux me botter » peut aussi signifier « je veux mettre des bottes » de la même façon que « je veux me chausser » veut dire « je veux mettre des chaussures ».</sub>

---

- (a) nobody would ever say that. When meaning to kick<sup>1</sup>, *botter* requires an object (*botter le derrière, botter en touche...*). A literal translation would be:

  > *je veux me botter les fesses pour avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.*

  That will be understood but it is unidiomatic.
- (b) is wrong. It means you are the one wanting to kick but without specifying who/what is kicked.
- (c) has the same issue than (a). *Moi-même* emphasizes the *je*.

I do not see any any idiomatic expression where someone wish to self-inflict kicks so here is what I would use:

> *Je m'en veux à mort d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.*

Note that this expression is widespread and much softer than it looks. To avoid *mort*, we might also say:

> *Je m'en veux sérieusement d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.*
>
> *Je m'en veux grave d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous hier.*

*Grave* is colloquial French and controversial here.

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's a little far fetched but *je veux me botter* might also mean *je veux mettre des/mes bottes* (I want to put my boots on) just like *je veux me chausser* means « je veux mettre mes chaussures » (I want to put my shoes on).</sub>

Comment: Hmm... Might that be too strong? How would it stack up against "I wish I were dead", for example?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Actually, I'm not against adding the figurative "à mort" to "m'en veux", since this "à mort" figuratively qualifies the idea of "(sooo) ashamed!": "I feel ashamed (*to the point of **dying of shame***) of myself for having done ...". I mean, rather than directly referring to "death" in its literal sense: "*I wish I were **dead***".

Comment: Merci ! Upvoté.

Answer (score 3):

You would not use a translation of "to kick", that would not be idiomatic in French. But you can use some phrases that suggest you would give slaps to yourself, which is a bit the same metaphor.

> Je me mettrais des claques d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous d'hier.
>
> Je mérite des claques d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous d'hier.
>
> Je me ficherais des claques d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous d'hier. (more familiar)
>
> Je me foutrais des claques d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous d'hier. (mildly vulgar)

You can also replace *claques* by *baffes*, which is more familiar. In spoken, you can also add un "en", eg *je m'en mettrais des claques d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous d'hier*.

Still using the same metaphor, there is this phrase: *être à baffer*

> Je suis à baffer d'avoir oublié le rendez-vous d'hier.

Comment: IMHO the most idiomatic are *je mérite des baffes* et *je suis à baffer*. *Je me mettrais/foutrais/ficherais des claques/baffes* can be heard but are less expected.