# « On en veut » : pourquoi « en » ?

Tags: usage, en

> On en veut aux professeurs de dispenser un enseignement inutile.

Pourquoi ce en dans la phrase ? C'est une manière d'éviter le subjonctif ?

Comment: It's actually a commonly used expression in conversation. I might just add that a someone that irritates you could be yourself: "***Je m'en veux de** ne pas y avoir pensé avant !*" Haven't you felt this way before? It is close to "*I want to kick myself for ...*" in English: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29008/traduction-de-kick-myself Also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/what-is-the-origin-of-en-vouloir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rien à voir avec le subjonctif, "en vouloir à" (+proposition infinitive en *de*) veut dire avoir de la rancœur pour quelqu'un. Le pronom est une part obligatoire de l'expression, totalement figé.

La valence habituelle de "vouloir" est "vouloir [quelque chose] [de quelqu'un]", mais il existe aussi un certain nombre d'expressions figées basées sur la valence "vouloir [quelque chose (d'indéfini)] à quelqu'un", où l'objet indirect animé est affecté par le souhait.

Cette seconde valeur de vouloir n'est plus productive, impossible de dire "je veux des malheurs au président" mais elle l'a été par le passé:

- "Voleir aucune rien à aucun" (Vouloir quelque chose à quelqu'un) - Citation du TLFi, qui la date de la moitié du Xe siècle mais donne pas de source
- "Cil Ewruïns molt **li vol miel** (Cet Ébroin-ci lui veut beaucoup de mal) - Vie de Saint-Léger, fin du Xe
- "Mes quant de Gauvain me recort comant ses pere ocist le mien, **je ne li puis voloir nul bien**" (Mais quand il me souvient de Gauvain comme son père tua le mien,  je ne peux lui vouloir aucun bien), Chrétien de Troyes, Perceval ou le conte du Graal

Cet usage persiste en français moderne dans les expressions "vouloir du bien/du mal à quelqu'un". Comme "du mal" se pronominalise avec "en", le pronom a fini par se figer, sans antécédent, dans les expressions "en vouloir à quelqu'un" et "s'en vouloir".

Answer (score 1):

Non, *On veut aux professeurs de...* serait incorrect.

Il s'agit ici de l'expression *[En vouloir à quelqu'un](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir)*.

2. En vouloir à qqn. Éprouver de l'hostilité, du ressentiment, de la rancune à l'égard de quelqu'un. *Je lui en veux à mort* (Vailland, *Drôle de jeu*, 1945, p. 257).

Comment: Merci. Ce n'est pas de français courant ?

Comment: *En vouloir à quelqu'un* est une expression très courante.

Comment: Merci encore ! Je ne l'ai jamais rencontrée jusqu'à aujourd'hui:-)!

Comment: Et donc l'usage de en est le même comme ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29903/pourquoi-est-il-correct-dutiliser-y-et-en-sans-ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dents et ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/la-fonction-de-en-dans-en-arriver-l%C3%A0?noredirect=1&lq=1 (sans antécédent) ?

Comment: *En vouloir à quelqu'un* est une expression toute faite qui doit donc être considérée telle qu'elle. Il est vain de vouloir chercher à la décomposer.

Comment: C'est bon. Merci pour la réponse et les commentaires !